# Linking various where/where not statements in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find out whether people who participated in events in rival Catholic Churches in the eighteenth-century Dutch Republic married each other. First, I start with the people who were baptized in rival churches:

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(m:marriage)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(pp:person)
WHERE (p)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht) AND (pp)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
```

However, it might be the case that after the baptism and before the marriage, people participated in events in a rival church, so I need to rule this out. This can be done by means of a WHERE NOT statement:

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(m:marriage)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(pp:person)
WHERE (p)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht) AND (pp)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
MATCH (p), (pp)
WHERE NOT (p)--(e:event)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church), (pp)--(ee:event)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht)
```

Here, however, I get stuck, because I need to specify that the events in which p and pp participated (e and ee) happened before the year of the marriage (m). This can be done by a WHERE statement:

```
WHERE e.Event_year > m.Event_year, ee.Event_year > m.Event_year
```

Howver, I've no clue how to connect everything together and to create one query that will do this for me.

Comment: Why do you need a second MATCH+WHERE? Can't you extend your `WHERE` with `AND` (and then simply connect the last WHERE)?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you require the event year to be `<` the marriage year?

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use `AND`?

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(m:marriage)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(pp:person)
WHERE (p)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht)
AND (pp)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
AND NOT (p)--(e:event)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
AND NOT (pp)--(ee:event)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht)
AND e.Event_year > m.Event_year
AND ee.Event_year > m.Event_year
```

You shouldn't have to double-MATCH with different WHERE clauses, since there are only two nodes to be matched.

Perhaps combine with `WITH`:

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(m:marriage)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(pp:person)
WHERE (p)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht)
AND (pp)-[:BAPTISED_AT]-(:event:baptism)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
WITH p, m, pp
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)--(e:event)
OPTIONAL MATCH (pp)--(ee:event)
WHERE NOT (p)--(e:event)--(:church:Roman_Catholic_Church)
AND NOT (pp)--(ee:event)--(:church:Church_of_Utrecht)
AND e.Event_year > m.Event_year
AND ee.Event_year > m.Event_year
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. I had to make a couple of changes to what you suggested in order to declare the variables 'e' and 'ee', but I got this working now:  `MATCH (p:person)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(m:marriage)-[:MARRIED_AT]-(pp:person), (p)--(e:event), (pp)--(ee:event)`  and then what you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jaap please check my updated answer, I have added `WITH`